# Use bullets as navigation with Swipe JS

Tags: javascript, html, slider, swipe.js

I've been banging my head off a wall for a few hours and I'd really appreciate some help with this. I know it's going to be easy solution but so far it's not going well.

I'm using Swipe Js for a slider and I want to use some bullets as navigation (without the next and prev). I tried to use getPos() a built in swipe function but I keep getting a 'no method' error in my console.

Here's my HTML:

```
<section id='slider' class='swipe full-width'>
      <div class='swipe-wrap'>

        <div class="slide">
          <!-- content -->
        </div>

        <div class="slide">
          <!-- content -->
        </div>
 </div>
</section>

 <div class="counter">
      <ul id='position'>
          <li class="on"></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
       </ul>
 </div>
```

Here's my JS: 
I've pulled it back to what's working. I just want to click on a dot and make it go to the corresponding slide.

```
   var slider = Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
      auto: 6000,
      continuous: true,
      callback: function(pos) {

        var i = bullets.length;
        while (i--) {
          bullets[i].className = ' ';
        }
          bullets[pos].className = 'on';
      }

    });

  var bullets = document.getElementById('position').getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Any help is really appreciated

Link to my code http://codepen.io/veryrobert/pen/sHjwo

Link to the plugin https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('li').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var index = $("li").index(event.currentTarget);
  slider.slide(index);
});
```

Basically, you need to workout the index of corresponding `li` and pass that to swipes `.slide` method. This will then slide to the requested slide.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for the help. I really really appreciate it. Here's an updated pen if anyone else needs it. http://codepen.io/veryrobert/pen/sHjwo

Comment: One issue I just notice is that now the timer is messed up, would there be a way to reset it? or should I add this into the callback?

Comment: The 'auto' stops working after the user interacts with it. I can't find anything in the docs that mentions how to restart it I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries Gary, I think I might move away from swipe js in this particular case and use something that has the built in functionality I need. Really appreciate your time and help on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Good idea, find one that works best for you instead of hacking it. Happy to help. I've not really used many others as I really how swipe feels on a touch device. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To make **bullets clickable**, you can use the plugin's pagination module and initialise it as follows:

```
<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    // Default parameters
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
</script>
```

In this way, swiper takes care of creating the bullets inside the element that is given as a parameter and set `clickable: true`

Remember to include/import the paging module with Swiper or include/import the Swipern bundle for navigation to work:

**From NPM:**

```
// core version + pagination module:
import Swiper, { Pagination } from 'swiper';

// configure Swiper to use module
Swiper.use([Pagination]);

// init Swiper:
const swiper = new Swiper(...);
```

**From CDN:**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```