# With Swiper.js, navigation via bullets sometimes doesn't go to correct slide

Tags: swiper.js

I'm using swiper.js in my project and sometimes (maybe 1 out of 10 times), navigation by clicking the associated bullet does not work - it instead goes to the previous slide. My swiper config object does contain `clickable: true` for the pagination.

Comment: I don't think your question has enough context for people to easily answer it. Could you for instance show the relevant code? And what have you tried to narrow down the problem? Does it happen in specific situations or is it completely arbitrary? etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [code](https://codepen.io/veryrobert/pen/sHjwo). I think someone had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328040/use-bullets-as-navigation-with-swipe-js)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Swipe 2</h1>

<div id='slider' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div><b>1</b></div>
    <div><b>2</b></div>
    <div><b>3</b></div>
   
  </div>
</div>
    
  <div class="counter content" style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
                 <ul id='position'>
                      <li class="on"></li>
                      <li ></li>
                      <li ></li>
                </ul>
  </div>
    
<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
  
  <button onclick='slider.prev()'>prev</button> 
  <button onclick='slider.next()'>next</button>

</div>

<script src='swipe.js'></script>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, footer, header, nav, section {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
  font-size:100%;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background:transparent;
}
body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  min-height:416px;
}
h1 {
  font-size:33px;
  margin:50px 0 15px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#212121;
}
h2 {
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#3c3c3c;
  margin:20px 10px 10px;
}
small {
  margin:0 10px 30px;
  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
}
a {
  margin:0 0 0 10px;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#3c3c3c;
}


html, body {
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

#console {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family:"Inconsolata", "Monaco", "Consolas", "Andale Mono", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #999;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#slider div b {
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#14ADE5;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px;
  padding:100px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px #EBEBEB;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #E5E5E5 #D3D3D3 #B9C1C6;
}

.swipe {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
}

.counter {
  height: 55px;
  ul {
    text-align: center;
    li {
      // padding: 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      border: solid 2px #404041;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin: 2.5px;
      &.on {
        background: #404041;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('slider');
        var slider =
        Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
          auto: 10000,
          continuous: true,
          callback: function(pos) {

            var i = bullets.length;
            while (i--) {
              bullets[i].className = ' ';
            }
              bullets[pos].className = 'on';
          }

        });

var bullets = document.getElementById('position').getElementsByTagName('li');

 $('li').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var index = $("li").index(event.currentTarget);
  slider.slide(index);
});

// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
```